# How to Redirect to the login page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` in my project.And I have a value called `auth` And I get it from `localStorage`
And I want to go to the login page when `auth` has no value ..How do I redirect?

```
  return (
            this.state.auth ?
           
                <div className="wrapper" >
                  
                    <div id='content' className={this.state.isSidebarActive ? "content" : "content-active"}>
            
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/main' >
                                <Redirect to='/main/customers/real' />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path="/main/access/deny"><NoAccess  isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>
                            ....
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
                : 
 <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' >
                            <Redirect to='/Login' />
                        </Route>
                       
                    </Switch>
        );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect on Login - React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921419/redirect-on-login-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why you separated the switch router statement but it's better you keep them together.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/main' > <Redirect to='/main/customers/real' /> </Route>

    <Route path="/main/access/deny"><NoAccess  isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>

    <Route exact path='/' > <Redirect to='/Login' /> </Route>

</Switch>
```

I also do not know why you are redirecting so many times. You may want to watch out for that before you enter into an eternal loop.

UPDATE

I like to be quite explicit with what am doing so I switched the ternary statement to the below.

```
    if(this.state.auth != null)
    {
        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div id='content' className={this.state.isSidebarActive ? "content" : "content-active"}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/main' >
                            <Redirect to='/main/customers/real' />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/main/access/deny"><NoAccess  isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>
                        ....
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Redirect to='/Login' />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
```

Try the code and let me know how that works for you.

Comment: When I clear the cache, the amount of auth is null ..I want to go to the login page when it is null..How should I do this?

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if that helped. If not let's figure it out together.

Comment: Glad to see! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a router guard, with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-guards) package you can create simply router guards.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GuardProvider, GuardedRoute } from 'react-router-guards';
import { About, Home, Loading, Login, NotFound } from 'pages';
import { getIsLoggedIn } from 'utils';
 
const requireLogin = (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.auth) {
    if (getIsLoggedIn()) {
      next();
    }
    next.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
 
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <GuardProvider guards={[requireLogin]} loading={Loading} error={NotFound}>
      <Switch>
        <GuardedRoute path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <GuardedRoute path="/" exact component={Home} meta={{ auth: true }} />
        <GuardedRoute path="/about" exact component={About} meta={{ auth: true }} />
        <GuardedRoute path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </GuardProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      <Router>
         <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
          
          <Route exact path='/admin/'>
           {userData?<Redirect to="admin/dashboard" />:<Redirect to="/"/>}
          </Route> 
        
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```